# Keep only sentences with a single word in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe for sentiment analysis with columns: PhraseID, Phrase, Rating.

I'd like to filter the dataframe such as to keep only rows in which the Phrase is made of a single word. The column Phrase contains of course strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this.

```
mask = df['Phrase'].str.match(r'\A[\w-]+\Z')
df[mask]
```

Or all in one line would be

```
df[df['Phrase'].str.match(r'\A[\w-]+\Z')]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more or less clean (but the pandas foo masters in here might come up with a one liner)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"PhraseID" : [1, 3, 4], "Phrase": ["hey what", "up", "no"]})

def f(x):
    return len(x.split())
df["n_words"] = df.Phrase.apply(f)
df[df.n_words == 1]
```

gives

```
    Phrase  PhraseID n_words
1   up       3         1
2   no       4         1
```

You can also do an anonymous function if you like instead:

```
df["n_words"] = df.Phrase.apply(lambda x : len(x.split()) )
```

Comment: Good use of split().  I like it

Answer (score 1):

One liner that returns a data frame containing only records with a Phrase of one word.

```
import pandas as pd
df[df.Phrase.apply(lambda x: len(x.split())== 1)]
```

This works assuming your phrases can be tokenized on with `split()`